# SQL Server Management Studio command line?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there a command line interface where I can run a script that says, for example:
Connect to server a
Run query 1
Connect to server b
Run query 2
Run query 3

I tried searching online but couldnt find anything built into SQL Server Management Studio.
Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The **sqlcmd Utility**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

It usually ships with the SQL Server installer and is located in the following directory by default:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to export in/out there is a command-line utility called BCP that will let you execute these types of processes.

[bcp Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)

> The bcp utility bulk copies data between an instance of Microsoft SQL
>   Server and a data file in a user-specified format. The bcp utility can
>   be used to import large numbers of new rows into SQL Server tables or
>   to export data out of tables into data files. Except when used with
>   the queryout option, the utility requires no knowledge of
>   Transact-SQL. To import data into a table, you must either use a
>   format file created for that table or understand the structure of the
>   table and the types of data that are valid for its columns.

Comment: Just thought I would add that your data file must be on the local instance or you must have access to the full network path of the file location.